# Comparing two folders and copy differences in another folder

Tags: windows, comparison

I want to compare `Dir1` with `Dir2` including subfolders for content ( the directory may contain binary data)

If there are differences, I want to create a `DiffDir` which has the changed or added files

```
Dir1    << My original directory
 \images
  |  a.jpg
 \src
   | a.src
   | b.src 
    \ lib
     |  a.lib
     |  b.lib

Dir2             << I copy Dir1, rename it to Dir2 , and start adding and changing files
 \images
  |  a.jpg
  |  b.jpg       << Add this
 \src
   | a.src
   | b.src       << Change this
    \ lib
     |  a.lib
     |  b.lib
     \newlib     << Add this
        a.newlib << Add this
        


DiffDir    << After changing Dir2, i am looking a way to build DiffDir like this
 \images
  |  b.jpg
 \src
   | b.src 
    \ lib
     \newlib     
        a.newlib
```

I tried **winmerge**, **FreeFileSync** but there was not such an option there.

Comment: Try to google for "Differential Backup Software", you'll find freeware as well as paid software.

Comment: If you are comfortable with PowerShell, you could `gci` the 2 folders, then use `compare-object` to get the difference and copy them to a newer folder.

Comment: Use rsnyc with cygwin or wsl. Or if you plan to code, git.

Answer (score 1):

You may write script to compare the two folders, in batch or PowerShell.

It might be simpler to use the free application
[ThirdDir](http://rva.mtg.sk//)
by Robert Vašíček.
Although from 2005, it still works in Windows.

For a review of the application, see the article
[Compare Directories and Copy Unique Files](https://www.ghacks.net/2008/07/17/compare-directories-and-copy-unique-files/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that this can be done with `winmerge`, after comparing ( make sue that `Tree Mode` is not enabled)

1. Select All files
2. Right Click and select `Zip > Differences too...`
3. Select a folder and it will create a `7z` file

The file has two folders: `altered` and `original`, which has the required changed files.

It will help if you de select `View > Show Identical Items`.

[image]